# jQuery getting ID

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the image SRC using this: `var SRCNow = $('#'+ID+'.item').attr("src");`

on this:

```
<a id='17' href='#' name='item' class='tilelink'><img title='17' id='17' style='background:red'; class='item' src='line_tile/t17.png' /></a>
```

So when I click on that image by doing on click image...: `var ID = $(this).attr("id");`

and then I do `alert(SRCNow);` and I get undefined.... when it should say the SRC.

Comment: there does not seem to be an id equal to ID + .'item' in your HTML

Comment: Why not use `$('.item', this)` instead of pulling out the `id` and concatenating it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have two elements with the same id.  This is not allowed.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp:

> Definition and Usage
>
> The id attribute specifies a unique id
>   for an HTML element.
>
> The id must be unique within the HTML
>   document.

Answer (score 1):

First, an html id must begin with a letter ( [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) ).

Your specific problem is, you must add a space between the id and the class `item`, like this:

`var SRCNow = $('#'+ID+' .item').attr("src");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a LINK as well as image with the ID 17. IDs should be unique. Also, IDs starting with a number are not valid (as far as I remember).

First make your IDs unique. Then you don't need the class filter when you're trying to grab the image src.

```
<a id='link-17' href='#' name='item' class='tilelink'>
    <img title='17' id='img-17' style='background:red'; class='item' src='line_tile/t17.png' />
</a>

var SRCNow = $('img-17').attr('src');
```

Or you can loop through your images

```
var srcs = []; //array of srcs
$('images.item').each(function(){
   srcs.push($(this).attr('src'));
})
```